# Diophantine Equations - 4th Powers / Computational Number Theory

Tags: diophantine-equations, computational-mathematics

I am looking for two integers, $a$ and $b$, such that $a^4+b^4=n$ and where $n$ is one of the six  numbers

```
11570282017820433013523535601, or 
11570314155463181637103702801, or
11572060353961555386606814001, or 
11572215695702429026631328801, or 
11573624522376724598676284401, or
11575215560569326509742400801
```

Can anyone give me a software program to check whether an integer  is the sum of two fourth powers ?

Answer (score 0):

$n=11570282017820433013523535601$ satisfies $7\mid\mid n$, i.e., $7\mid n$ and $7^2\nmid n$, so that $n$ is not the sum of two squares, according to the Fermat's [criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares). But then $n=a^4+b^4=(a^2)^2+(b^2)^2$ is impossible, too.

For $n=11570314155463181637103702801$ we have $2699\mid\mid n$, and $2699\equiv 3 \bmod 4$, hence also not of the form $x^2+y^2$. Similarly for thers, e.g. $n=11572215695702429026631328801$, see the comment of vrugtehagel.

However, $n=11572060353961555386606814001$ is the sum of two squares. With pari gp, sage or another CAS we can check whether it is a sum of two fourth powers, or not.

Comment: Similarly, we can eliminate $11572215695702429026631328801$ since it's divisible by $103$ only once