# Can 13477627276039606281933936961 be expressed as a sum of two fourth powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

Is  13477627276039606281933936961 the sum of two  fourth powers?  I suspect that this number is the sum of two fourth powers.  Can anyone use Wolfram Mathematica or SAGE to check whether this number is the sum of two  fourth powers ?

Comment: Where did you get this number

Comment: I know the complete factorization of this number which is      13477 627276 039606 281933 936961 = 17 × 38833 × 43753 × 466611 825530 925017.  two of the factors are of the form 16n+1  and two of them are of the form 16n+9.  Hence I think it is possible that this number is the sum of two fourth powers

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183873/diophantine-equations-4th-powers-computational-number-theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is small enough to brute force.

Edit: fixed number

```
import gmpy2
N = 13477627276039606281933936961

for x in range(1, int((N**0.25)/2)+1):
    if gmpy2.is_square(N - x**4):
        print(x, (N-x**4)**0.25)
```

Output:

```
3330955 10749966.0

>>> 3330955**4 + 10749966**4 == 13477627276039606281933936961
True
```

Comment: Thanks very much qwr !! What software package or programming language did you use  to solve this problem ?  I  use wolfram Mathematica, but the following command Solve[x^4+y^4 == 13477627276039606281933936961 , {x,y} , Integers]  fails to solve this problem.  Mathematica claims that there are no integers  x  and y which satisfy this equation.  But clearly as you have shown , there are !!

Comment: @Derek I tried Mathematica as well, but it did not actually solve the problem. I used python here, which is not the fastest language but for $N^{1/4} \approx 10^7$ it is good enough.

Comment: @qwr In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2363211/4781) a few months from this one, the OP mentions that he was looking for counter-examples to Euler's Quartic Conjecture (already settled by Elkies). A database of $a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1855884/4781) but the terms $3330955^4 + 10749966^4$ do not appear. It's unfortunate the OP didn't clarify what this sum of two fourth powers would imply. (OP is no longer active in MSE.)