# Can $406014677132263504491682$ be the sum of two fourth powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

Can $406014677132263504491682$ be the sum of two fourth powers? It may be so.   Can anyone use Wolfram Mathematica , SAGE , or some computer program, to check whether this number is the sum of two fourth powers ?

The complete factorization of this number is given by : $406014 677132 263504 491682 = 2 × 1459 × 6883 × 21529 × 938976 705857$

Comment: Where are these numbers coming from and is there any reason you aren't using wolfram alpha?

Comment: ._. The majority of your questions are these seemingly random "Can ____ be written as the sum of ____ ____th powers?"  Surely you must've learned something from your previous questions so that you could better show your attempts at the problem?

Comment: I  am searching  for counterexamples  to the Euler Quartic Conjecture . These numbers  turn up as part of my search for counterexamples .  Unfortunately  Wolfram Mathematica , and Wolfram Alpha  are unable to solve this type of problem. They are not reliable.  Sometimes they claim there are no integer solutions, whereas  in fact there may be !

Comment: Nope, the number can't even written as a sum of two squares because $1459 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Comment: If you are looking at this conjecture, presumably you already know of the disproof of it by Elkies (1988) as found on the Mathworld page.  So the next step would be to look at that work and figure out what class of solutions was found.  Have you done this?

Comment: @achillehui gave a simple theoretical answer. Also, in PARI/GP, the simple program `a=406014677132263504491682;for(i=0,a^(1/4),ispower(a-i^4,4)&&return(i))` proves by brute force that no solution exists.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen:  I don't program in PARI/GP, but doesn't your code merely test whether $a$ is itself expressible as a fourth power, not that it is expressible as the *sum* of two terms, each of which is a fourth power?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The code looks correct to me, assuming there is a solution, one of the summands would be less than the other and in particular, less than the 1/4th power of a (or 4th power root), call this 'i'. Now go through all possible 'i' and check if (a-i^4) is a fourth power. That seems like what the code does

Comment: @mdave16:  Ah... Thanks.  Got it!

Comment: @Derek Yes, Wolfram Mathematica can answer a question like this:   For example, type `FindInstance[(280286069726155265499093303843106==x^2+y^2)~And~(x==z^2)~And~(y==w^2),{x,y,z,w},Integers]` into [the wolfram cloud sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com) and use Shift+Enter or numpad Enter or clicking on "Evaluate Cell" to run it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try some program like this in future for testing.

However, I cannot say anything myself about how the program handles precision, etc, with taking $4$th powers and roots of large numbers, but at least you can be sure it's possible if the program returns with a positive (as you can verify it yourself).

---

https://js.do/

```
<script>

var a = 406014677132263504491682;

var b = Math.pow(a / 2.0, 0.25);

var c = -1;

for (var i = 1; i <= b; i++) {

    if (Math.pow(a - Math.pow(i, 4), 0.25) % 1 == 0) {c=i; break;}
}

document.write(c);

</script>
```

---

Some quick testing with random examples such as $32$ and $280286069726155265499093303843106=12371235^4+129387197^4$ seem to work, though.

Comment: Javascript numbers are always IEEE 754 "double precision", which do not have the precision to represent integers of this size exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm.  $1459^1$.  Any whole number where a $4n-1$ prime has an odd exponent can't be rendered as a sum of squares.  Let alone fourth powers.