# Is $524154366113525716400386$ the sum of two fourth powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

Is $524154366113525716400386$ the sum of two fourth-powers? I suspect that this number is the sum of two fourth powers. Can anyone use a computer program, or SAGE, or Wolfram Alpha to check whether this number is the sum of two fourth- powers?

The complete factorization of this number is given by : 
$$524154 366113 525716 400386 = 2 × 521 × 8761 × 21529 × 221281 × 12 052297$$   Notice that all the factors are of the form $16n+1$ or $16n+9$ (They are all congruent to $1$ or $9 \mod16$ ). Hence this number may be the sum of two-fourth powers.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363211/can-406014677132263504491682-be-the-sum-of-two-fourth-powers).

Comment: where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: If it is such a sum, then one of the powers is divisible by $5$, since the final digit of a 4th power is 0, 1, 5, or 6, and your number ends with $6$, hence comes from either $ 1 + 5$ or $0 + 6$.

Comment: I used PARI/GP and brute force : The number isn't the sum of two $4$-th powers.

Comment: @Peter .  I am searching for counterexamples  to the Euler Quartic Conjecture .  This particular  number turns up in my search  and as far as I can tell,  it has all the right properties to make it the sum of two  fourth powers.  For example , this number is congruent to 9 (mod 13) !!

Comment: @Derek: afaik the euler quartic conjecture is already disproven

Comment: ? n=524154366113525716400386;k=sqrtnint(n,4);for(a=0,k,if(ispower(n-a^4)>0,print
(a))) is the program I used. There is a more efficient way (necessary for larger $n$), but I do not remember at the moment how it works

Comment: @supinf I guess, Derek is searching for more counterexamples.

Comment: @Derek It was a difficult task to disprove the conjecture you mentioned. Numbers do not tend to be the sum of two $4$ th powers, a sum of two squares occurs significantly more often.

Comment: @Peter a sum of two fourth powers is a sum of squares of squares I believe to be the cause.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Perhaps, I formulated it unlucky. The chance that a number is the sum of two $4$-th powers is much less than the chance that it is the sum of two squares.

Comment: I get that but to be a sum of fourth powers it is a necessary condition that it be a sum of two squares (of squares).

Comment: @JohnHughes: Both last digits need to be odd because there is only one factor of 2 in the final sum; therefore 0+6 can also be eliminated as well. $(a+b)^4+(a-b)^4=2\left( \left( a^2+b^2 \right)^2 +(2ab)^2 \right)$

Comment: @Peter oh and another thing in this case sqrtint(sqrtint(n)) is actually faster.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee sqrtnint(n,4) is the truncated value of $n^{1/4}$

Comment: I know I play around in PARI/GP console a lot. sqrtint(sqrtint(n)) is smaller ( okay tested it maybe not but it was slightly quicker to use) yet can be proven to be an upper bound. fourth powers are squares of squares. So an integer square, that doesn't exceed n, needs to have a base of at most sqrtint(n). but we also need the base to be an integer square. The largest integer value that can work as the base for this square is sqrtint(sqrtint(n)) hence it's the upper bound on any value whose fourth power doesn't exceed n, as well as the other properties needed.

Answer (score 1):

In case you were not aware, [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerQuarticConjecture.html) mentions Elkies' disproof, citing [On $A^4+B^4+C^4=D^4$](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0930224-9/S0025-5718-1988-0930224-9.pdf).

Without having any software installed on your computer, you can check that this particular number is not the sum of two fourth powers by, say, pasting `FindInstance[(524154366113525716400386524154366113525716400386==x^2+y^2)~An‌​d~(x==z^2)~And~(y==w‌​^2),{x,y,z,w},Intege‌​rs]` into [the wolfram cloud sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com) and use Shift+Enter or numpad Enter or clicking on Gear>"Evaluate Cell" to run it. (For confirmation that this code would work, compare to using `280286069726155265499093303843106`.)

There may be some modular congruences that rule this number out as well.